# Cannot create a new query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My SQL Server Management Studio has some issues. I cannot create a new query.

Every time I click on "New Query", Management Studio stops then restarts.

My laptop is running Windows 8.1

Comment: This is not the right section, try http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: only SSMS stops then  restarts

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) try short-cut key CTRL+N to open a new query window.

Comment: the point is that i cant create a new query no matter which way i use.

Comment: What tool are you using, Is it SSMS which you run as as Administrator?